# Composer update stuck on my views... I think

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Here is the commande:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

The rest is just html from two of my views. Why is it doing this exactly? Is there a way around this?

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site",
"description": "Laravel 4 Starter Site",
"keywords": ["laravel","Starter Site"],
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Andrew Elkins",
        "homepage": "http://www.andrewelkins.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "dev-master",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master",
    "jasonlewis/basset": "dev-master",
    "robclancy/presenter": "dev-develop",
    "j20/php-uuid": "dev-master",
    "greggilbert/recaptcha": "*",
    "league/oauth2-server": "2.1.x",
    "league/oauth2-client": "dev-master",
    "zetacomponents/database": "1.4.6",
    "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "1.0.x",
    "filp/whoops": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "dev-master",
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev",
    "summerstreet/woodling": "0.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/library",
        "app/models",
        "app/presenters",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/library"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: And your `composer.json`?

Comment: Your `composer.json` looks fine, did you get any informative error message ? What `HTML` code about those `views` you are talking about ?

Comment: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

Comment: [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output: